# Fast date and time conversion

Tags: python, performance, pandas, datetime, time

I have data that looks like this:

```
       DATE             TIME_M EX    BID    ASK SYM_ROOT  SYM_SUFFIX
0  20180312  9:30:00.052465558  V  41.67  43.77     TRIP         NaN
1  20180312  9:30:00.207724531  B  41.66  43.61     TRIP         NaN
2  20180312  9:30:00.208090941  K  40.80  44.76     TRIP         NaN
3  20180312  9:30:00.208116618  Z  41.62  43.83     TRIP         NaN
4  20180312  9:30:00.208691471  V  40.76  43.77     TRIP         NaN
```

In order to make it look like this:

```
        DATE EX    BID    ASK          time
0 2018-03-12  V  41.67  43.77  34200.052466
1 2018-03-12  B  41.66  43.61  34200.207725
2 2018-03-12  K  40.80  44.76  34200.208091
3 2018-03-12  Z  41.62  43.83  34200.208117
4 2018-03-12  V  40.76  43.77  34200.208691
```

I created the following function:

```
def transform_date_time(file):
    # Transform DATE format to include hiffens:
    file['DATE'] = file['DATE'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y%m%d'))

    # Join DATE and TIME_M
    file["newtime"] = pd.to_datetime(file["DATE"].astype(str) +" "+ file["TIME_M"].map(str))

    # Get seconds from midnight
    file["midnight"] = pd.to_datetime(file["DATE"].astype(str) + " " + "00:00:00.000000000")
    file['time'] = file["newtime"] - file["midnight"]  # in timedelta format
    file['time'] = file['time'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())

    # Delete columns that will not be used
    columns = ['SYM_ROOT', 'SYM_SUFFIX','TIME_M','newtime','midnight']
    file.drop(columns, inplace=True, axis=1)

    return file
```

So, what I am doing is transform the `DATE` column to include hyphens and the `TIME_M` column turns into a 'time' column that is now seconds from midnight instead of a regular 24 hour time.

My problem is that this takes a while to run. Is there a more efficient way to do the same thing?

Comment: how long does this take? And what are you running it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way with `pandas`.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['TIME_M'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME_M']).dt.total_seconds()
```

In general, avoid `lambda` as this is just a poorly disguised and generally inefficient loop.

Note that your output for date is a `datetime` object. Internally, it is represented as an integer. The dashes are just there for presentation.

If you *really* need the dashes, you need to convert *back to string*, something I wouldn't recommend unless absolutely required.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime conversions can be expensive. So let's try to avoid them where possible:

Most obvious optimization:

The same date and time (up to the decimal) are repeated, so it would be better to only do the conversion when they change, and use the result of the last conversion as long as they stay the same (for the data that will probably be a lot of times).

When they change you don't even have to use datetime conversions in your case. For the date you can simply insert the `'-'` using substring, and for the time it would be easy to calculate the seconds without converting to time or datetime first. Just extract the 3 parts, multiply by 3600, 60 and add the seconds.